# Bazel build failure

Tags: ios, bazel, bazel-rules, xcframework

I have iOS application built with bazel. After particular dependency (MyLib) update Bazel build started to fail with the following error:

```
ERROR: /Projects/ios/MyLib/BUILD:10:33: in apple_dynamic_xcframework_import rule //ios/MyLib:MyLib: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/external/build_bazel_rules_apple/apple/internal/apple_xcframework_import.bzl", line 513, column 65, in _apple_dynamic_xcframework_import_impl
        cc_info = framework_import_support.cc_info_with_dependencies(
    File "/external/build_bazel_rules_apple/apple/internal/framework_import_support.bzl", line 90, column 68, in _cc_info_with_dependencies
        (compilation_context, _compilation_outputs) = cc_common.compile(
Error in compile: at index 20 of public_hdrs, got element of type NoneType, want File
ERROR: /Projects/ios/MyLib/BUILD:10:33: Analysis of target '//ios/MyLib:MyLib' failed
ERROR: Analysis of target '//ios:MyApp' failed; build aborted:
```

MyLib is a simple pre-built dynamic framework and does not define imported headers explicitly. From what I can see it's internal structure did not change after the update (no new files were added):

```
apple_dynamic_xcframework_import(
            name = "MyLib",
            visibility = [
                "//visibility:public",
            ],
            xcframework_imports = glob(["MyLib.xcframework/**"]),
        )
```

What can cause that error and how can I debug it further?